# R and RStudio not detecting installed PostgreSQL (or any other) ODBC drivers

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio, rodbc, rpostgresql

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using the R ODBC drivers in RStudio. For some reason, the drivers are not being detected by R:

```
$ Rscript -e 'odbc::odbcListDrivers()'
[1] name      attribute value    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Even though as far as I can tell, they are correctly installed (using homebrew):

```
$ brew list
freetds     gettext     git     icu4c       libtool     openssl     pcre2       pkg-config  
postgresql  psqlodbc    readline    sqlite      sqliteodbc  unixodbc

$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/barthf/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[PostgreSQL Driver]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so

[SQLite Driver]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.dylib

$ ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep odbc.*so$
libsqlite3odbc.so
libtdsodbc.0.so
libtdsodbc.so
psqlodbca.so
psqlodbcw.so
```

I am running on:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DBI_1.0.0  odbc_1.1.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18      dbplyr_1.1.0      compiler_3.4.2    pillar_1.2.3      later_0.7.1       plyr_1.8.4       
 [7] bindr_0.1.1       base64enc_0.1-3   tools_3.4.2       digest_0.6.12     bit_1.1-12        jsonlite_1.5     
[13] tibble_1.4.2      nlme_3.1-131      lattice_0.20-35   pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.2.2       psych_1.7.8      
[19] shiny_1.0.5       rstudioapi_0.7    parallel_3.4.2    RPostgreSQL_0.6-2 yaml_2.1.14       bindrcpp_0.2.2   
[25] stringr_1.2.0     httr_1.3.1        dplyr_0.7.5       sparklyr_0.8.4    hms_0.4.2         rprojroot_1.2    
[31] bit64_0.9-7       grid_3.4.2        tidyselect_0.2.4  glue_1.2.0        R6_2.2.2          foreign_0.8-69   
[37] tidyr_0.7.2       reshape2_1.4.2    purrr_0.2.5       blob_1.1.1        magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.1  
[43] promises_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6   mnormt_1.5-5      assertthat_0.2.0  mime_0.5          xtable_1.8-2     
[49] httpuv_1.4.0      stringi_1.1.5     lazyeval_0.2.1    broom_0.4.2
```

For some reason unknown to me, the `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()` driver works fine. However I want to use the ODBC driver so I can make use of the RStudio Connections feature. When I try to use RStudio to create a `New Connection` the dialog window only shows options for connecting to `Livy` and `Spark`.

As suggested, here is the attempted connection code:

**Using `ODBC`:**

```
> con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
+                       driver = "PostgreSQL Driver",
+                       database = "postgres",
+                       UID    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
+                       PWD    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
+                       host = "localhost",
+                       port = 5432) ## returns error below
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'PostgreSQL Driver' : file not found
```

**Using `RPostgreSQL`:**

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(),
+   dbname = "postgres",
+   user    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
+   password    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
+   host = "localhost",
+   port = 5432) ## works fine
```

Any thoughts why the R ODBC drivers do not seem to work? Any suggestions on things that I can try here?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my post to add these in

Comment: Please output the environment variable, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You need to set the odbc lib directory to it: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: So I checked `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using `Sys.getenv` and it seems to be empty. Then I set it using `Sys.setenv` but am still getting: `Can't open lib 'PostgreSQL Driver' : file not found`

Comment: Where is the `export` directive? Try doing this in command line outside R first.

Comment: No luck, tried using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH...` in shell before starting R, using `system()`, using `Sys.setenv`, adding the export statement to `~/.Renviron` and using the terminal tab in RStudio but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: This can be a permissions issue in the `/etc`. Try running R as root or the owner of the folder and test odbc connection.

Comment: OK awesome thanks it looks like you're correct and it's a permissions issue! I first tried `sudo Rscript -e 'odbc::odbcListDrivers()'` which (for some unknown reason) does not work BUT then I just tried `cp /etc/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini && Rscript -e 'odbc::odbcListDrivers()` and that shows two drivers. Awesome.

Comment: Check permissions and ownership with `ls -l /etc`. If root, try changing to your user `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /etc`

Comment: Actually using `~/.odbcinst.ini` solved my issue, showing that it was indeed a permissions issue as you suggested. I'd rather not touch the `/etc` permissions. Happy to accept your answer if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: I was following through the same issues and I had missed one crucial step. I did not edit the `odbcinst.ini`. I followed through the steps [here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/#odbcinst.ini) and the connection worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else still stuck on this issue - I spent a couple of hours trying to get the `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` command to print out the drivers I knew were on my Mac.

I normally use a windows machine and never had this issue before, so was kind of out of my depth trying to figure it out.

There are a couple of questions on StackOverflow and in the issues section of **r-dbi/odbc** github with various answers - but none worked for me.

I thought I’d post a detailed answer to how I solved it for my Mac.

RStudio has a guide on setting up drivers for Windows/Mac/Linux machines. After installing unixODBC and your drivers (PostgreSQL for example) you are meant to edit the following two files `odbcinst.ini` (defines driver options) and `odbc.ini` (defines connection options).

On my Mac, I didn’t know where to look so I went searching and found it at `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini`.

This file had the driver information in it that I assumed would show up using `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` - but wasn't.

After a lot of googling, I found the following command to type into mac terminal `odbcinst -j` to (i think) show the file location of driver and data source name information. This displayed the location of the odbc.ini file at the following path `/Users/myusername/.odbc.ini`.

Note the leading dot in `.odbc.ini`.

The dot denotes hidden files. Type `SHIFT + CMD + .` to display them.

After navigating to `/Users/myusername` and displaying hidden files, I saw `.odbcinst.ini` also. I opened this file in a text editor and surprise, it was empty.

I opened up `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini`, copied the contents and pasted them into `/Users/myusername/.odbcinst.ini`.

I jumped back into the R console and finally, I could return values using `odbc::odbcListDrivers()`.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, you could install [the driver](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) and add your data source in "ODBC Data Source Administrator", e.g. with the name of "DATA_SOURCE_NAME".

The following code will work if you have saved the password in your ODBC Data Source Administrator.

```
install.package('DBI')
install.package('odbc')
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn='DATA_SOURCE_NAME', driver="PostgreSQL Unicode")
```

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]